# Is it equipment abuse to hit hard a ball hard towards a croquet hoop?

Tags: croquet

I've looked through [The WCF Rules of Golf Croquet](https://worldcroquet.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/WCF-GC-Rules-6th-Edition-Final-7.3.22.pdf), but can't find anything specific for this sitation:

Suppose an opponent's ball is touching a hoop on the opposite side to the player's ball, and the player deliberately hits his ball as hard as possible *towards the hoop,* but with no intention of *directly* contacting the opponent's ball (intending the motive force to be transferred *through the hoop upright* to the opponent's ball).

I want to know if that constitutes "abuse of equipment" under rule 16.2.3, which outlaws any play...

> *...which physically abuses the player’s mallet **or other equipment***

Comment: This is definitely on-topic at Sports, welcome along all (once you create accounts here :) )

Comment: @PhilipKendall: I'm not holding my breath waiting for a "clear-cut unambiguously correct" Answer, but thanks for the welcome. If not today, maybe there'll be dozens of Golf Croquet aficionados on this site in a few years time! :)